# I get "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" for some reason

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server

I am trying to implement a rezervation of a table.

A page has a combo-box of tables and input fields. I choose a table, pick a date, enter a number of customers and press *Proceed*. Then it sends me to a page with input fields. I input information about a customer and add him to the list. I can also add more customers. If it's enough, I press *Reserve*.

It's supposed to show a page telling me that it was successful, but instead I get:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`Upis`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Upis_Musterija1` FOREIGN KEY (`idMusterija`) REFERENCES `Musterija` (`idMusterija`))
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1320) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:994) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3375) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3908) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3290) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2425) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at jdk.proxy8/jdk.proxy8.$Proxy170.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.demo.controller.RezervacijaController.rezervisi(RezervacijaController.java:92) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1787) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

SQL scripts and tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Musterija` (
  `idMusterija` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ime` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `prezime` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `adresa` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `brTelefona` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idMusterija`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

CREATE TABLE `Upis` (
  `idRezervacija` int NOT NULL,
  `idMusterija` int NOT NULL,
  KEY `fk_Upis_Musterija1_idx` (`idMusterija`),
  KEY `fk_Upis_Rezervacija1_idx` (`idRezervacija`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Upis_Musterija1` FOREIGN KEY (`idMusterija`) REFERENCES `Musterija` (`idMusterija`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Upis_Rezervacija1` FOREIGN KEY (`idRezervacija`) REFERENCES `Rezervacija` (`idRezervacija`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

CREATE TABLE `Rezervacija` (
  `idRezervacija` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brMusterija` int NOT NULL,
  `datumRezervacije` datetime NOT NULL,
  `cenaRezervacije` double NOT NULL,
  `idSto` int NOT NULL,
  `idUser` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idRezervacija`),
  KEY `fk_Rezervacija_Sto1_idx` (`idSto`),
  KEY `fk_Rezervacija_User1_idx` (`idUser`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Rezervacija_Sto1` FOREIGN KEY (`idSto`) REFERENCES `Sto` (`idSto`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Rezervacija_User1` FOREIGN KEY (`idUser`) REFERENCES `User` (`idUser`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

[image: tables]

Rezervacija.java:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Rezervacija.findAll", query="SELECT r FROM Rezervacija r")
public class Rezervacija implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idRezervacija;

    private int brMusterija;

    private double cenaRezervacije;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date datumRezervacije;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Musterija
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="Upis"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="idRezervacija")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="idMusterija")
            }
        )
    private List<Musterija> musterijas;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Sto
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idSto")
    private Sto sto;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idUser")
    private User user;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Upis
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="rezervacija")
    private List<Upis> upis;

    public Rezervacija() {
    }

    public int getIdRezervacija() {
        return this.idRezervacija;
    }

    public void setIdRezervacija(int idRezervacija) {
        this.idRezervacija = idRezervacija;
    }

    public int getBrMusterija() {
        return this.brMusterija;
    }

    public void setBrMusterija(int brMusterija) {
        this.brMusterija = brMusterija;
    }

    public double getCenaRezervacije() {
        return this.cenaRezervacije;
    }

    public void setCenaRezervacije(double cenaRezervacije) {
        this.cenaRezervacije = cenaRezervacije;
    }

    public Date getDatumRezervacije() {
        return this.datumRezervacije;
    }

    public void setDatumRezervacije(Date datumRezervacije) {
        this.datumRezervacije = datumRezervacije;
    }

    public List<Musterija> getMusterijas() {
        return this.musterijas;
    }

    public void setMusterijas(List<Musterija> musterijas) {
        this.musterijas = musterijas;
    }

    public Sto getSto() {
        return this.sto;
    }

    public void setSto(Sto sto) {
        this.sto = sto;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<Upis> getUpis() {
        return this.upis;
    }

    public void setUpis(List<Upis> upis) {
        this.upis = upis;
    }

    public Upis addUpi(Upis upi) {
        getUpis().add(upi);
        upi.setRezervacija(this);

        return upi;
    }

    public Upis removeUpi(Upis upi) {
        getUpis().remove(upi);
        upi.setRezervacija(null);

        return upi;
    }

}
```

Sto.java:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Sto.findAll", query="SELECT s FROM Sto s")
public class Sto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idSto;

    private int brMesta;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Rezervacija
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="sto")
    private List<Rezervacija> rezervacijas;

    public Sto() {
    }

    public int getIdSto() {
        return this.idSto;
    }

    public void setIdSto(int idSto) {
        this.idSto = idSto;
    }

    public int getBrMesta() {
        return this.brMesta;
    }

    public void setBrMesta(int brMesta) {
        this.brMesta = brMesta;
    }

    public List<Rezervacija> getRezervacijas() {
        return this.rezervacijas;
    }

    public void setRezervacijas(List<Rezervacija> rezervacijas) {
        this.rezervacijas = rezervacijas;
    }

    public Rezervacija addRezervacija(Rezervacija rezervacija) {
        getRezervacijas().add(rezervacija);
        rezervacija.setSto(this);

        return rezervacija;
    }

    public Rezervacija removeRezervacija(Rezervacija rezervacija) {
        getRezervacijas().remove(rezervacija);
        rezervacija.setSto(null);

        return rezervacija;
    }

}
```

Upis.java:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Upis.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM Upis u")
public class Upis implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private UpisPK id;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Musterija
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idMusterija", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Musterija musterija;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Rezervacija
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idRezervacija", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Rezervacija rezervacija;

    public Upis() {
    }

    public UpisPK getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(UpisPK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Musterija getMusterija() {
        return this.musterija;
    }

    public void setMusterija(Musterija musterija) {
        this.musterija = musterija;
    }

    public Rezervacija getRezervacija() {
        return this.rezervacija;
    }

    public void setRezervacija(Rezervacija rezervacija) {
        this.rezervacija = rezervacija;
    }

}
```

UpisPK.java:

```
@Embeddable
public class UpisPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private int idRezervacija;

    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private int idMusterija;

    public UpisPK() {
    }
    public int getIdRezervacija() {
        return this.idRezervacija;
    }
    public void setIdRezervacija(int idRezervacija) {
        this.idRezervacija = idRezervacija;
    }
    public int getIdMusterija() {
        return this.idMusterija;
    }
    public void setIdMusterija(int idMusterija) {
        this.idMusterija = idMusterija;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(other instanceof UpisPK)) {
            return false;
        }
        UpisPK castOther = (UpisPK)other;
        return 
            (this.idRezervacija == castOther.idRezervacija)
            && (this.idMusterija == castOther.idMusterija);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * prime + this.idRezervacija;
        hash = hash * prime + this.idMusterija;
        
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Musterija.java:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Musterija.findAll", query="SELECT m FROM Musterija m")
public class Musterija implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idMusterija;

    private String adresa;

    private String brTelefona;

    private String email;

    private String ime;

    private String prezime;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Narudzbina
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="musterija")
    private List<Narudzbina> narudzbinas;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Rezervacija
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="musterijas")
    private List<Rezervacija> rezervacijas;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Upis
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="musterija")
    private List<Upis> upis;

    public Musterija() {
    }

    public int getIdMusterija() {
        return this.idMusterija;
    }

    public void setIdMusterija(int idMusterija) {
        this.idMusterija = idMusterija;
    }

    public String getAdresa() {
        return this.adresa;
    }

    public void setAdresa(String adresa) {
        this.adresa = adresa;
    }

    public String getBrTelefona() {
        return this.brTelefona;
    }

    public void setBrTelefona(String brTelefona) {
        this.brTelefona = brTelefona;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getIme() {
        return this.ime;
    }

    public void setIme(String ime) {
        this.ime = ime;
    }

    public String getPrezime() {
        return this.prezime;
    }

    public void setPrezime(String prezime) {
        this.prezime = prezime;
    }

    public List<Narudzbina> getNarudzbinas() {
        return this.narudzbinas;
    }

    public void setNarudzbinas(List<Narudzbina> narudzbinas) {
        this.narudzbinas = narudzbinas;
    }

    public Narudzbina addNarudzbina(Narudzbina narudzbina) {
        getNarudzbinas().add(narudzbina);
        narudzbina.setMusterija(this);

        return narudzbina;
    }

    public Narudzbina removeNarudzbina(Narudzbina narudzbina) {
        getNarudzbinas().remove(narudzbina);
        narudzbina.setMusterija(null);

        return narudzbina;
    }

    public List<Rezervacija> getRezervacijas() {
        return this.rezervacijas;
    }

    public void setRezervacijas(List<Rezervacija> rezervacijas) {
        this.rezervacijas = rezervacijas;
    }

    public List<Upis> getUpis() {
        return this.upis;
    }

    public void setUpis(List<Upis> upis) {
        this.upis = upis;
    }

    public Upis addUpi(Upis upi) {
        getUpis().add(upi);
        upi.setMusterija(this);

        return upi;
    }

    public Upis removeUpi(Upis upi) {
        getUpis().remove(upi);
        upi.setMusterija(null);

        return upi;
    }

}
```

RezervacijaController.java:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rezervacije")
public class RezervacijaController {

    @Autowired
    RezervacijaRepository rr;
    @Autowired
    MusterijaRepository mr;
    @Autowired
    StoRepository sr;
    @Autowired
    UpisRepository ur;

    @GetMapping(value = "popuniStolove")
    public String popuniStolove(HttpServletRequest request) {
        List<Sto> stolovi = sr.findAll();
        request.setAttribute("stolovi", stolovi);
        return "rezervacijaStola";
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value = "unesiRezervaciju")
    public String unesiRezervaciju(Integer brMusterija, Date datum, Sto sto, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Rezervacija r = new Rezervacija();
        r.setBrMusterija(brMusterija);
        r.setCenaRezervacije(800.0 * brMusterija);
        r.setDatumRezervacije(datum);
        sto.addRezervacija(r);
        sr.updateSto(sto);
        
        List<Musterija> musterije = new ArrayList<Musterija>();
        request.getSession().setAttribute("musterije", musterije);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("rezervacija", r);
        return "unosMusterija";
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @PostMapping(value = "/dodajMusteriju")
    public String dodajMusteriju(String ime, String prezime, String adresa, String email, String brTelefona, HttpServletRequest request) {
        List<Musterija> musterije = (ArrayList<Musterija>) request.getSession().getAttribute("musterije");
        Musterija m = new Musterija();
        m.setIme(ime);
        m.setPrezime(prezime);
        m.setAdresa(adresa);
        m.setEmail(email);
        m.setBrTelefona(brTelefona);
        musterije.add(m);
        request.setAttribute("musterije", musterije);
        return "unosMusterija";
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @PostMapping(value = "rezervisi")
    public String rezervisi(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Rezervacija r = (Rezervacija) request.getSession().getAttribute("rezervacija");
        List<Musterija> musterije = (ArrayList<Musterija>) request.getSession().getAttribute("musterije");
        
        for (Musterija m : musterije) {
            Upis upis = new Upis();
            UpisPK uPK = new UpisPK();
            uPK.setIdMusterija(m.getIdMusterija());
            uPK.setIdRezervacija(r.getIdRezervacija());
            upis.setId(uPK);
            ur.save(upis);
            mr.save(m);
        }
        
        rr.save(r);
        return "uspehRezervacija";
    }
    
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        sdf.setLenient(true);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(sdf, true));
    }

}
```

Repositories:

```
public interface UpisRepository extends JpaRepository<Upis, UpisPK> {

}
```

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class StoRepoSpecificImpl implements StoRepoSpecific {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void updateSto(Sto sto) {
        try {
            em.merge(sto);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

```
public interface StoRepoSpecific {

    public void updateSto(Sto sto);
    
}
```

```
public interface StoRepository extends JpaRepository<Sto, Integer>, StoRepoSpecific {

}
```

You can see my public [project](https://github.com/IgorArnaut/MIS-Picerija) on Github.

Comment: You need to contain your problem in a minimal viable way.  In its current state, its too much text and code for anyone to read.  People are more motivated to answer if they see a "conceptual" question.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL-Server